# The file "Demo" Couldn't be opened because you don't have permission to view it

Tags: xcode10.1

This question was asked several times in StackOverflow.
[image]
[The file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774731/the-file-couldn-t-be-opened-because-you-don-t-have-permission-to-view-it)

[The file “ ” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355105/the-file-couldn-t-be-opened-because-you-don-t-have-permission-to-view-it/53425582#53425582)

[File couldn't be opened because you don't have permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445471/file-couldnt-be-opened-because-you-dont-have-permission),

[The file “***.app” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103048/the-file-app-couldn-t-be-opened-because-you-don-t-have-permission-to-view),

and etc

> It seems like the problems everyone faced is the same Xcode error,
>   like below, but totally different causes.

[image]

> For me, the error will appear when I use the wrong Building Setting.
>   So Why Xcode gave the same error to the specific problems. Or In the
>   eyes of Xcode, these problems belong to the same type of error, so how
>   does Xcode classify these errors?
>   [image]